Expo-camera onBarcodeScanned doesnt work with ios devices
In my expo app I am using expo-camera for scanning barcodes(ean13)  it works with android but on iOS only the camera opens, scan doesn't work.
Nothing happens. onBarcodeScanned not triggering.
I also changed barcodecode for like 'qr' but nothing happened camera opens but doesnt scan the ean13 codes I expected.
<CameraView
  onBarcodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
  barcodeScannerSettings={{
    barCodeTypes: ["ean13"],
  }}
  style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
/>


Does it work if you remove the conditional? How are you storing the scanned variable? Are you sure it's initially false? Otherwise, this should be working.
